# How to configure pom file to download specific jar files?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, pom.xml, nexus

I have a simple Maven project and I want to download from Nexus repo JavaFX jars. The problem is that it downloads the jar files depending on the OS.
POM example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

Nexus example:
[image]

Now, how can I download all javafx-controls-11-xxx.jar files for all platforms? When uploading this to Jenkins it will download only the Linux jars and I need all of them to make the project cross platform.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It downloads based on the platform it gets deployed to be a cross-platform. Is that not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. 
Using this `<classifier>linux|mac|win</classifier>` solves the problem. I have to add a classifier for all jar files.

Comment: Where do you use it? `<classifier>` tag on the dependency?

Comment: @Aaron, here is an example: 
 `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Nevermind, I see it was Stackoverflow hiding `<XML tags>` in your answer. Thanks for your feedback !